# Java Input as Variable Name

Tags: java, database, input

I want to make a program to get information from a list, by entering a code. E.G:

'Enter the code:'

> My input:  d001

Then I want to print out information that belongs to this code. The information belongs to the String named 'd001', so in this case I want my input to be the name of the variable I am going to print out. How do I do this? Or is there a better solution to get information from a database list by entering the code name for it?
I could make a huge switch statement, but this is not efficient coding. I got this now:

```
public class Main {

    public static Scanner idScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int diseaseId = 0;

    /** ID Scanning and reading: */
    public static void executeId() {
        diseaseId = idScanner.nextInt();
        switch (diseaseId) {
        case 001:
            System.out.println(IdListener.d001);
            break;

        case 002:
            System.out.println(IdListener.d002);
            break;

        case 003:
            System.out.println(IdListener.d003);
            break;

        case 004:
            System.out.println(IdListener.d004);
            break;

        case 005:
            System.out.println(IdListener.d005);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(LayoutListener.titleString); /** Title String Display */
        System.out.print(LayoutListener.idField); /** ID field Display */
        executeId();
    }
}

public class IdListener {
    public static String d001 = "[Neuroblastomia]: Tumor that grows on the nerves of the spine.";
    public static String d002 = "[Anorexia]: Mental disease to avoid eating and consuming.";
    public static String d003 = "[TEMP3]: TEMP3.";
    public static String d004 = "[TEMP4]: TEMP4.";
    public static String d005 = "[TEMP5]: TEMP5.";
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt use interfaces for that... just as info

Answer (score 1):

Using a Map may be a better solution to what you want to do.

```
Map<String, String> diseases = new HashMap<String, String>(); // Map<ID, Description>
diseases.put("d001", "[Neuroblastomia]: Tumor that grows on the nerves of the spine.");
diseases.put("d002", "[Anorexia]: Mental disease to avoid eating and consuming.");
// the rest of your diseases
```

So that when `String disId = "d001"` it will make things a lot simpler and you will not have a giant switch statement.

```
if(diseases.containsKey(disId))
    System.out.println(diseases.get(disId));
else
    System.out.println("That id does not exist!");
```

Comment: How do I use this with the input scanner?

+ I fixed the errors by putting it in the main method.

Comment: To use it with the input scanner you would do for example `String disId = idScanner.nextLine();`

Comment: Thanks alot! How can I access the map when I want it in a different class? So my main class won't get that messy?

Comment: You could declare it as `public static` outside of the main method.

Comment: That doesn't work, when I declare the map outside of the main method at the other class, and add the items in the main method, and then try to access it at my other class as 
  if(IdListener.diseases.containsKey(diseaseId))
      System.out.println(IdListener.diseases.get(diseaseId));

Comment: Okay, but what error comes up when you do that?

Comment: No error, just when I enter code d001 when I run it, nothing will show.

Comment: You doing the user input after you add everything to the map right? Add `else System.out.println("The id ["+disId+"] does not exist");` after the if just to be sure.

Comment: It says that the code does not exist. How to fix this? How can I add the things first to the map before calling the input method? My whole map and map items are on the other class.

Comment: You could for example add everything to the map in a method `public static void createDiseases()` in the IdListener class. Then back in your main method you would run `IdListener.createDiseases();` at the beginning before user input.

Comment: I did, but then I get an error at the 'IdListener.diseases.containskey...', saying diseases cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: You have the Map as a global variable in the class and not inside a method right?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it. Awesome!! Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection

Field f= IdListener.class.getDeclaredField("d"+input);
f.get(null);

Comment: How do I use this?

Comment: remember that reflection slows down your code.  Use it as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing question.

You mention databases but show no code or explanation for that.

## Octal

One important flaw in your code: Do no use leading zeros on a numeric literal. The leading zero means the number should be interpreted as an octal number (base-8) rather than as a decimal (base-10).

So, `case 001:` should be `case 1:`.

## Enum

If you have only a few of these disease codes, and they do not change during the runtime of your app, [learn to use an enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). The enum facility in Java is much more powerful and flexible than in other languages.

## Map

If the set of disease codes may change during runtime, and you have few enough of these to all fit comfortably into memory, then use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) collection. A map tracks a bunch of objects ("keys") each of which is associated with another object (a "value"). Like a common dictionary book which tracks a bunch of words, and each word is assigned the text of a definition; each word is a key mapped to a value (it's definition).

In your case an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) key (code number) maps to a `String` value (disease title/description). If you know a code number, you can ask the map to locate the matching disease title.

## Database

If you have many of these diseases, too many to all fit into memory, use a database. For example the [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Whenever you have a code number, query the database for the matching disease title.

You will need to learn about SQL and [JDBC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, very interesting and educating!